# C++ Handle to wstring

Tags: c++, string, handle

I have the following code to convert a HANDLE to a wstring. 
I was thinking that I was on a good way, but I just can not get it right.

```
wstring handleToWString(HANDLE uHandle)
{
    std::wostringstream str;
    std::wstring ws;
    str << uHandle;
    str >> ws;

    wstring s(str.str());

    return s;
}
```

The line

```
    str >> ws;
```

fails, saying that there is no such operator for this operation.

Can somebody help?
Thank you.

Comment: Why not just `str << uHandle; return str.str();`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you have the following

```
std::wostringstream str;
```

which means it is "output" stream.

change it to

```
std::wstringstream str;
```